# How to send long String to HC05 bluetooth module from bluetooth terminal app

Tags: android, terminal, bluetooth, serial-communication, hc-05

I am using [Github link](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothTerminal) App [App link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=en&gl=US) to send a long string with 108 characters to my Bluetooth module
String is (101122000000000030250130280000000000000000000000001000183000000000000000000000000000211000200011000001200000) but i am getting string as (100003025013028000000000000000000000000100018300000000000000000000000000021100020001100000120000000000000000)
Help me to send the correct data from the terminal to the HC05 .